# sort by date in Advanced Custom Field

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, meta-query, order

I am trying to filter posts with certain values and sort by the date field using ACF module. I have succeeded in filter with package and type. But when i added date sort, its not working. Please help me. Can we filter and sort simultaneously using ACF?

```
<?php 
$package = $_GET['package'];
$type = $_GET['type'];
$sort = $_GET['sort'];

$filterquery = array('relation' => 'AND');

if (isset($package) && $package != "All")
{
    $filterquery[] =  array(
            'key' => 'package',
            'value' => $package,
            'compare' => '='
        );
}

if (isset($type) && $type != "All")
{
    $filterquery[] =  array(
            'key' => 'type',
            'value' => $type,
            'compare' => '='
        );
}

if (isset($sort))
{
    $filterquery[] =  array(
            'meta_key' => 'sortdate', // name of custom field
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        );
}   
else
{ 
    $filterquery[] =  array(
            'meta_key' => 'sortdate', // name of custom field
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'order' => 'DESC'
        );

}



  $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'    => 6,
        'cat'       => '4',         
        'meta_query' => $filterquery,


        );          


$query = new WP_Query($args); ?>
```

Comment: What does "its not working" mean? What does it do or not do that you expect it to do?

Comment: its filtering with package and type. But order by date not working..

Comment: could you please help me?

Comment: Honestly, what do you think I'm doing? And why do you think that impatience is going to help? Not 20 minutes has past since my first comment.

Comment: Your meta query is wrongly constructed, you are using invalid parameters inside your meta query

Comment: Thank Pieter Goosen. I have already fixed it myself. The mistake i have done is, the orderby should be called externally, not inside $filterquery.

Comment: @ShyamKrishnaSreekumar Glad you solved this! Could you please post your solution as an answer (and accept it) so this question isn't listed in our unanswered list? Thanks :)